# Django REST Framework - Serializing optional fields

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have an object that has optional fields. I have defined my serializer this way:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    code = serializers.Field(source="Code")
    classification = serializers.CharField(source="Classification", required=False)
```

I [thought](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#core-arguments) `required=False` would do the job of bypassing the field if it doesn't exist. However, it is mentioned in the documentation that this affects deserialization rather than serialization.

I'm getting the following error:

```
'Product' object has no attribute 'Classification'
```

Which is happening when I try to access `.data` of the serialized instance. (Doesn't this mean it's deserialization that's raising this?)

This happens for instances that do not have `Classification`. If I omit `Classification` from the serializer class it works just fine.

How do I correctly do this? Serialize an object with optional fields, that is.

Comment: Is it acceptable for those fields to be serialized as `None`, or should the key not be present at all?

Comment: They are not present at all, I'm calling a SOAP web service which has optional fields using suds, the response object represents the XML returned which in certain cases doesn't include the optional field.

Comment: Tom I have just realized what you meant; ideally I would like to have them not to be present at all, however I can live with `None` for the time being.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The serializers are deliberately designed to use a fixed set of fields so you wouldn't easily be able to optionally drop out one of the keys.

You could use a [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to either return the field value or `None` if the field doesn't exist, or you could not use serializers at all and simply write a view that returns the response directly.

**Update for REST framework 3.0** `serializer.fields` can be modified on an instantiated serializer. When dynamic serializer classes are required I'd probably suggest altering the fields in a custom `Serializer.__init__()` method.

Comment: Considering how friendly the framework has been for my project so far, it would be nice to have an out of the box option for keys that do not exist to default to `None`.

Comment: @TomChristie Hey Tom, now that DRF 3 is out, would you be able to update your answer for the recommended way of doing this using DRF 3? I'm asking because a couple of people are suggesting different ways using DRF 3 and I'm not sure what the best option is (see Mark's answer below or see David's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015931/remove-null-fields-from-django-rest-framework-response for examples of ways to accomplish this using DRF 3. What would you say is the best way using DRF 3?)

Answer (score 35):

The method describe below did the work for me.
Pretty simple,easy and worked for me.

DRF version used = djangorestframework (3.1.0)

```
class test(serializers.Serializer):
  id= serializers.IntegerField()
  name=serializers.CharField(required=False,default='some_default_value')
```

Comment: Update:
This worked for me and I am using Django 4 with DRF ver 3.14.0.
The "allow_blank" idea did not work. Since it will still need an empty string to be passed to be valid and accepted.

Answer (score 28):

**Django REST Framework 3.0+**
Dynamic fields now supported, see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields -- this approach defines all of the fields in the serializer, and then allows you to selectively remove the ones you don't want.

Or you could also do something like this for a Model Serializer, where you mess around with Meta.fields in the serializer init:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('code',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if SHOW_CLASSIFICATION: # add logic here for optional viewing
            self.Meta.fields = list(self.Meta.fields)
            self.Meta.fields.append('classification')
        super(ProductSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You'd have to ask Tom though if this is the "correct way" since it may not fit in with the long term plan.

**Django REST Framework < 3.0**
Try something like this:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
    classification = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_classification')

    def get_classification(self, obj):
        return getattr(obj, 'classification', None)
```

**Multiple Serializers**

Another approach would be to create multiple serializers with different sets of fields.  One serializer inherits from another and adds additional fields.  Then you can choose the appropriate serializer in the view with the `get_serializer_class` method.  Here's an actual example of how I use this approach to call different serializers to present different user data if the user object is the same as the request user.

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    """ An authenticated user looking at their own user object gets more data """
    if self.get_object() == self.request.user:
        return SelfUserSerializer
    return UserSerializer
```

**Removing fields from representation**

Another approach that I've used in security contexts is to remove fields in the `to_representation` method.  Define a method like

```
def remove_fields_from_representation(self, representation, remove_fields):
    """ Removes fields from representation of instance.  Call from
    .to_representation() to apply field-level security.
    * remove_fields: a list of fields to remove
    """
    for remove_field in remove_fields:
        try:
            representation.pop(remove_field)
        except KeyError:
            # Ignore missing key -- a child serializer could inherit a "to_representation" method
            # from its parent serializer that applies security to a field not present on
            # the child serializer.
            pass
```

and then in your serializer, call that method like

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    """ Apply field level security by removing fields for unauthorized users"""
    representation = super(ProductSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    if not permission_granted: # REPLACE WITH PERMISSION LOGIC
        remove_fields = ('classification', ) 
        self.remove_fields_from_representation(representation, remove_fields)
    return representation
```

This approach is straightforward and flexible, but it comes at the cost of serializing fields that are sometimes not displayed.  But that's probably okay.

Comment: This is often task to show data conditionally based on permission, i wondering that there is no comfortable way to handle it.
It's look like your first approach will work, but it's kind of monkey patching, and your ProductSerializer.Meta.fields will increase every time you create new instance and you will lost it's first state

Comment: @meteor I added another example at the end of how I solve this problem these days for security uses.  I don't recommend using the example that you mentioned any more.

Comment: Isn't the first example pretty close to the suggestion from the documentation? I'm a noob and confused as to why that's not a good approach?

Source: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields

Comment: Maybe -- this answer was originally written a long time before there a standard way to do it  :-) .  If I were you I would follow the example in the documentation to get started.  At one time or another I've used each of these techniques though, so it's possible that in certain special cases they are still relevant to some.

Answer (score 6):

The serializers `Charfield` method has a property `allow_blank`

By default it is set to False.
Setting it to `True` will allow you to mark the field as optional during "serialization".

This is the code that you should write

```
classification = serializers.CharField(source="Classification", allow_blank=True)
```

Note: `required` property is used for deserialization.

Answer (score 3):

**DynamicSerializer** for DRF 3, which allows dynamicly specifying **which fields will be used in serializer, which will be excluded**, and optionally which will become required!

1. Create Mixin

```
    class DynamicSerializerMixin:
        """
        A Serializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
        controls which fields should be used.
        """

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
            fields = kwargs.pop("fields", None)
            excluded_fields = kwargs.pop("excluded_fields", None)
            required_fields = kwargs.pop("required_fields", None)

            # Instantiate the superclass normally
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            if fields is not None:
                # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
                allowed = set(fields)
                existing = set(self.fields)
                for field_name in existing - allowed:
                    self.fields.pop(field_name)

                if isinstance(fields, dict):
                    for field, config in fields.items():
                        set_attrs(self.fields[field], config)

            if excluded_fields is not None:
                # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
                for field_name in excluded_fields:
                    self.fields.pop(field_name)

            if required_fields is not None:
                for field_name in required_fields:
                    self.fields[field_name].required = True
```

2. **Initialize/adjust your serializer** by adding DynamicSerializerMixin to inheritence

```
class UserProfileSerializer(DynamicSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            'first_name', 'last_name'
            "email",
            "is_staff",
        )
```

3. **Use it** :)

```
class RoleInvitationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    invited_by = UserProfileSerializer(fields=['id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
```

or **in action apis**

```
    @action(detail=True, serializer_class=YourSerialzierClass)
    def teams_roles(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        queryset = user.roles.all()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True, excluded_fields=['user'])
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose the serializers have the `partial` argument. If when the serializer is initialized you can pass `partial=True`. If you are using generics or mixins you can overrider the `get_serializer` function as follows:

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['partial'] = True
    return super(YOUR_CLASS, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

And that will do the trick.

**Note:** This allows all fields to be optional and not only a specific one. If you want only specifics, you can override the method (i.e. update)  and add validations of existence for various fields.

Answer (score 1):

What has worked well for me is to set the serializer like so:

`classification = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, allow_blank=True, default=None)`

Answer (score 0):

From the "it's a terrible hack relying on specific implementation details of both DRF and Django, but it works (at least for now)" files, here's the approach I used to include some additional debugging data in the response from a "create" method implementation on a serializer:

```
def create(self, validated_data)
    # Actual model instance creation happens here...
    self.fields["debug_info"] = serializers.DictField(read_only=True)
    my_model.debug_info = extra_data
    return my_model
```

This is a temporary approach that lets me use the browsable API to display some of the raw response data received from a particular remote service during the creation process. In the future, I'm inclined to keep this capability, but hide it behind a "report debugging info" flag in the creation request rather than returning the lower level info by default.