# DjangoRestFramework - correct way to add "required = false" to a ModelSerializer field?

Tags: django, serialization, deserialization, django-rest-framework

This is my serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('user', 'post', 'reblog',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        post = Post(
                user =  validated_data['user'],
                post = validated_data['post'],
        )

        post.save() 

        # manually create a list of "reblog" users
        post.reblog.add(validated_data['user'])

        return post
```

and this is my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    reblog = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Now, I don't want my reblog field to ever be null in the database (it can be an empty list, but not null). So I did not set "null=True" in the model field. However, the end user should not have to provide a list of "reblog" users when creating a post (I'll do that manually in the create() mtehod).

I know that here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments it says I can add "required = false" to a serializer field but the fields I am using in my serializer are directly coming from the model (i.e., fields = ('reblog')).

From my understanding, I can't add "required = false" to my model because here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/ it does not mention "required" as a parameter to a model field.

With that said, how can I get my "reblog" ModelSerializer field to not be required during serailzation / deserialization?

Edit: the view which handles the post request sent is:

```
class post_list(APIView):
    """
    List all posts or create a new post.
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

pip freeze:

```
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Django==1.8
djangorestframework==3.1.1
uWSGI==2.0.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the parameter `blank=True` to the model field:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    reblog = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
                                         #^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, the parameter may be omitted on requests, but it may never be a `NULL` value.

### Altogether now:

`urls.py` (with `serializers.py` essentially inlined):

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from proj.models import Post



# Serializers define the API representation.
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('user', 'post', 'reblog',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        post = Post(
                user =  validated_data['user'],
                post = validated_data['post'],
        )

        post.save() 

        # manually create a list of "reblog" users
        post.reblog.add(validated_data['user'])

        return post
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'Post', PostViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

`models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    reblog = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True,related_name='reblog_users')
```

Now, when I send the POST request:

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "post": "foo"
}
```

It returns:

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "post": "foo",
    "reblog": [
        1
    ]
}
```

`pip freeze`:

```
Django==1.8.4
djangorestframework==3.2.4
```

Comment: hm interesting. I added "blank=True" to the model field but when I try to post JSON data without a reblog key-value pair, DRF says that reblog is required. I read the documentation on "blank=True" here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/ and it says that "If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value". So it is dealing with forms (django ModelForms I'm assuming), and since I am using a serializer, I think the serializer isn't taking into consideration "blank=True".

Comment: It worked for me.  How are you testing this?  Are you using the browseable API's HTML Form?  If so, try the Raw Data tab with the exact JSON you want.  Sometimes the HTML form doesn't work.

Comment: Also, you're right that the `blank` parameter is use by Django forms.  However, under the hood, DRF uses some of the Django forms logic and functions.

Comment: When you open up the python shell (python manage.py shell) and do >>>post = PostSerializer(data={"user":1,"post":"foo"}) >>>post.is_valid() does it return True or False? If it returns False, what's the output for >>>post.errors? I updated my post to show my current APIView which handles the request (maybe my issue is in my view).

Comment: It does return `True`.  I just tried it.  What versions are you using? `pip freeze`  I think we need a full [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to reproduce the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Also, why not use the `viewsets.ModelViewSet` as your base class.  Do you really need to create an `APIView`?  Are there other details in the implementation?

Comment: I just updated my code to use viewsets.ModelViewSet. I copy pasted what you posted above. I updated my post to include my pip freeze results (I am using DRF 3.1.1 while you are using DRF 3.2.4). For me, it is still saying that usersVoted is required for some reason. I'll review my code again in a couple hours. Maybe it's because I'm using DRF 3.1.1. Maybe updating to DRF 3.2.4 will solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's the version you're using. I downgraded to 3.1.1 and I see the issue you're having.  `pip install djangorestframework==3.2.4` and your error will go away.