# Django Rest Framework - Serializing based on content of the fields

Tags: django, serialization

I have the following model in my django project:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    ownerId = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/',
                              blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='Videos/',  
                             blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created', )
```

And my serializer class looks like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'ownerId', 'image', 'video')
```

As you can see, there is a Post class representing a post. The user should be able to post images, videos and also text to the backend. What I want was: If the user posts only a text ( and leaves out the image and video fields) then the Post class should be representing a Text post. If the user posts just an image ( and leaves the text and video fields unfilled) then it should be an Image post. And so on...
So, based on which field is filled, the Post class should be representing an image post, video post or text post (or maybe a combination of some fields together, e.g. a text with an image) - I think you get the idea.

Now, I tried to solve that problem with a `blank=True` attribute. And that outputs me this ( for a Text post for example) :

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "text": "Having great time",
  "ownerId": 1,
  "image": null, 
  "video": null
}
```

As you can see, image and video are set to null. But what I want is this for a text post:

```
 {
   "id": 3,
   "text": "Having great time",
   "ownerId": 1

 }
```

Is that possible in Django ? If not, how can I model a case like this ?

Comment: This thread will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015931/remove-null-fields-from-django-rest-framework-response

Comment: override the to_representation method in serializer class

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem