# Remove null fields from within an array in a Django Rest Framework response

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a question, which is simiar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015931/remove-null-fields-from-django-rest-framework-response?noredirect=1).

I'm using django-rest-framework to build an API, using ModelSerializer to return data from a model. The models holds Arrays (using the [PostgreSQL ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/)).

**models.py**

```py
    class FashionData(models.Model):
        image_urls_norm = ArrayField(models.TextField(null=True), null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class ProductLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        result = super(ProductLineSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        return OrderedDict([(key, result[key]) for key in result if result[key] is not None])

    class Meta:
        model = FashionData
        fields = ('image_urls_norm', )
```

(I'm overriding the `to_representation` function to remove any null fields from the response as outlined in [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1383790/simon)'s  response to the original question above)

**output**

```json
"image_urls_norm": [
                "https://somewebsite.com/image.jpg",
                null,
                null,
                null
            ],
```

The first item in the array is always going to be populated, but the subsequent items can be `null`

My question is, how can I remove the `null` items from array in the API response?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
class ProductLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        def to_representation(self, instance):
            result = super().to_representation(instance)
            return OrderedDict([(key, result[key]) for key in result if instance.image_urls_norm[key] is not None])
```

Comment: Thanks Swati, but that gives a `Type Error` list indices must be integers or slices, not str