# How to show model only if user and article has the same token in django Rest-Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two api's:

Article api:

```
{
"id": 2,
"title": "123",
"author": 2,
"showing_this": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "lol",
    }
],
"token": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "token": "123"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "token": "qweqer"
    }
]
},
```

User api:

```
{
"email": "a@a.com",
"token": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "token": "123",
    }
    {
        "id": 2,
        "token": "aaa",
    }
]
```

}

How can I only show "showing_this" in Article api if token in article api matches token in user api?

This is my Article serializer:

```
class ArticleSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
showing_this = ShowingThisSerializer(many=True)
Token = TokenSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)


class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = ['id', 'title', 'author', 'showing_this', 'token']
```

Token serializer:

```
class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Token
    fields = ['id', 'token',]
```

Showing this serializer:

```
class ShowingThisSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ShowingThis
    fields = ['id', 'title',]
```

Models:

```
class ShowingThis(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name="showings", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Token(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Token model from USER API:

```
class Token(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(NewUser, related_name="tokens", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(settings.TOKEN_MODEL, related_name="tokens", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Is it possible to create permissions in ArticleSerializer? How can I map through users' tokens and compare to the ones in the article and if there is a match than show content in "showing_this".

Comment: Could you please add the relationships among the models? This information is not enough to give a correct answer.

Comment: @gripep I added article api serializers and models.

Comment: In your models, how do you know which articles have which tokens, and which users have which tokens? do you have intermediate models representing that many to many relation?

Comment: @Alucarder yes sorry, it creates in User api, I added it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly permissions but you could filter your to_representation in the serializer

New answer based on comments:

based on this [Remove null fields from Django Rest Framework response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015931/remove-null-fields-from-django-rest-framework-response)

what you need to do is change the ArticleSerialzier

```
class ArticleSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    showing_this = ShowingThisSerializer(many=True)
    Token = TokenSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'author', 'showing_this', 'token']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        result = super(ArticleSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        response = []
        for key in result:
            if key == 'showing_this':
                user_token_ids = self.content['request'].user.token_set.values_list('id',flat=True)
                if any(article_token['id'] in  user_token_ids for article_token in result['token']):
                    response.append((key, result[key]))
            response.append((key, result[key]))
        return OrderedDict(response)
```

Old answer: I thought you would want to filter articles

this would filter articles by matching user tokens

```
class ArticeleViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    serializer = ArticleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_match_ids= Token.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).values('article_id')
        queryset = Article.objects.filter(id__in=user_match_ids)
        return queryset
```

Comment: This is nice, but I need to render all articles. I just don't want to show "showing_this" context if user token doesn't match

Comment: can you explain me user_token_ids?

Comment: self.content['request'].user is to get the user logged in who made the request, by your models, a user should a have a token set, and then we just want to grab the ids of the tokens of that set, an alternative would be Token.objects.filter(user_id=self.content['request'].user.id).values('id',flat=True)