# Django serialize optional field

Tags: python, django

I am beginner to Django. Currently, I can serialize like this.

```
Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    sound_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_sound_url')

    class Meta:
        model = Dialogue
        fields = ('id','english', 'sound_url') 

    def get_sound_url(self, dialogue):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        sound_url = dialogue.sound.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(sound_url)
```

Model

```
class Dialogue(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    english = models.TextField(max_length=400000)
    sound = models.FileField(upload_to='dialogues',blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.english)
```

However, since it is optional field, it show error like this.

I have read this also. But, I am not sure how to apply for my case. How shall I do?

[Django REST Framework - Serializing optional fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552380/django-rest-framework-serializing-optional-fields)

[image]

Comment: show us your model too pls

Comment: I have added model now @yedpodtrzitko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to account for the possibility of `dialogue.sound` being `None`, so try something like:

```
def get_sound_url(self, dialogue):
    if not dialogue.sound:
        return ''
    request = self.context.get('request')
    return request.build_absolute_uri(dialogue.sound.url)
```

Comment: or `return None` whatever you prefer

Answer (score 0):

Create a check in your `get_sound_url` method, for when `sound` is `None`, before trying to access the `sound.url` field.

```
def get_sound_url(self, dialogue):
     if not dialogue.sound:
        return None
     request = self.context.get('request')
     sound_url = dialogue.sound.url
     return request.build_absolute_uri(sound_url)
```

And then, Django REST framework serializers can have a field [`allow_null`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#allow_null). Try setting it to `true`, and check:

```
sound_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_sound_url', allow_null=true)
```