# How can we append extra fields dynamically in serializer.py using request object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

http://127.0.0.1:8000/?words=anger

and I want to add 'anger' to the field serializer dynamically.

```
from .models import Synonym
from rest_framework import serializers

class SynonymSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:        
        model = Synonym
        fields = ('word',)
```

Comment: Could you provide some details? We need something to work with to be able to help.

Comment: If you want to have different fields in the serialiser based on your GET parameters, you might wanna check this repo https://github.com/wimglenn/djangorestframework-queryfields

Comment: There are a whole bunch of approaches in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552380/django-rest-framework-serializing-optional-fields/25728065#25728065 including four different ways that I suggest.

Comment: Are these fields decalred in the model or you need add define them in the serializer on the fly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i have 7 columns in the database and 1 is must i.e word. then later i will pass query parameter using url i.e words and that is my second field attribute i want to add to my serializer. so there is any way which i can get it from request object.